# How to add Constant values in dropdown using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular Js.I am trying to use angular constants in my application as shown in the code below, i am able to alert constant values but i am not able to bind the constant values in view by using ng-repeat

1.index.html

```
<html ng-app="objApp" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ObjectiveController">
<form>
<select>
<option ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdown.regular>{{dropdown.name}}</option>
 </select>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

2. app.js

   ```
      var app = angular.module('objApp', ['ObjectiveControllers'])
      app.constant('dropdown', {
      regular: [
      {id: 1, name: 'daily'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Weekly'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Monthly'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Yearly'}
      ]
      });
   ```
3. controller.js

   ```
   var objectiveControllers = angular.module('ObjectiveControllers', []);

   objectiveControllers.controller('ObjectiveController', ['dropdown', function (dropdown) {
   alert(dropdown.regular);
   }]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to simply doesn't use the same name for your repeated object than the one you are fetching ?

like that:

```
ng-repeat="drop in dropdown.regular"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign dropdown to `$scope` :

`$scope.dropdown = dropdown;`

Answer (score 0):

Assign Constant Value to $scope variable

```
    objectiveControllers.controller('ObjectiveController', ['dropdown', '$scope',function (dropdown, $scope) {
    $scope.dropdown=dropdown;
    }]);
```

Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oZlnjzHBoJaCsghEVUFC?p=preview)

Also Read Below Articles:

[Constants & Values: Global Variables In AngularJS](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/)

[AngularJS Modularization & Dependency Injection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html#constants)

Answer (score 0):

You  need to use constant variable and assign $scope variable to it as constant aren't recognized in dom like $scope variable .

change following and it will work.

In js controller.

```
 $scope.val =  dropdown.regular;
```

and 
In html

```
     <select>
     <option ng-repeat="dropdown in val ">{{dropdown.name}}</option>
     </select>
```